# AWS Bahrain Region - No CodePipeline Yet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, cicd

As AWS codepipeline is not yet available on Bahrain region.

How can we achieved CI/CD? I have already created a script to transfer the code to S3.

But my problem is, how to automatically trigger codedeploy when a new zip code is uploaded to S3 so I would not to do the manual deployment everytime. Does someone have a lambda for this? Thank you.

Hope someone has a workaround on this limitation :)

Comment: The pattern you need is to create an s3 NotificationConfiguration/LambdaConfiguration when the file is uploaded. A quick search and this seems to be a reasonable example for that - https://windix.medium.com/s3-bucket-notification-to-lambda-in-cloudformation-without-circular-reference-f8f56ec5342c. Search for examples of codedeploy in your chosen lambda runtime, there are plenty -a python one here https://gist.github.com/webhacking/5d1ec3732c17092571a54145f13270e7

Comment: Thank you @RonanCunninghamm, I'll take a look on this one.